# Counting the number of digits in a number - which of these two solutions is faster?

Tags: algorithm, execution-time

I was asked in an interview recently how would I write an algorithm to count the number of digits in a given number. So for example if I was given a number 500 the result would be 3. If I was given a number 15345 the result would be 5.

I came up with 2 possible solutions:

1. Recursively divide the number by 10 until the result is less than 1 and then return the count of recursions I made.
2. Convert the number to string and then count the number of elements in this string.

Then I was asked which operation is more efficient when working with extremely large numbers and I couldn't give a good answer. So my question is what is the correct answer here - which algorithm is faster and why?

Comment: How about iteratively divide the number by 10 until the result is less than 10?

Comment: If it's a really big number - how is it represented? an `int` or even a `long` won't be enough. What language?

Comment: @TedHopp Yeah that was my solution but my question is which one of 2 solutions I gave is faster when working with large numbers?

Comment: Also, another way to do it is `floor(log_10(n)) + 1`

Comment: The person interviewing me just said very large number no type was given...

Comment: Converting to a string is often done by repeatedly dividing by 10, accumulating the remainders modulo 10, and then reversing to get them in the right order. #1 is a subset of #2's operations.

Comment: @A.Webb So if that is the case then number 1 would be quicker?

Comment: @A.Webb That really depends on the representation. I don't think the question can be answered as it is right now.

Comment: @amit Much moreso, the most efficient method can't be determined without the representation or time vs space tradeoff. It is probably neither #1 nor #2 if you are trying to optimize purely for time for example. Given only those choices and typical representations though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to convert an integer to a string, the basic `itoa` (integer to string) function works somewhat like this:

```
result = ""
while (number > 0)
{
    digit = number % 10
    append digit to result
    number = number / 10
}
```

So, there isn't that much of a difference between your first and your second solution. The first solution will take *O(n)* iterations, where *n* is the number of digits in the integer. The second solution will have the same complexity, and additionally count the *n* digits in the string in *O(n)* time, for a total of *O(2n)* = *O(n)* complexity.

Other algorithms are possible. For example, you might take a look at the highest bits that are set, and match those against a table of values.

Comment: The question is NOT about big O notation, it is about execution time. constants do matter.

Comment: @amit Without an actual implementation, you can say _literally nothing_ about execution time. The only statements one can make with such a general overview of an algorithm are about the time complexity.

Comment: I know, that's why I voted to close instead of answering a question which cannot be answered. The only thing I can tell from this question is it is not about big O notation, and the answer provided does not answer the question, regardless of the implementation.

Comment: @amit You're wrong. This is definitely an answerable question. Look, I just gave an answer above: neither is faster. Additionally, I think there is an _O(1)_ algorithm for this.

Comment: I am not wrong, without knowing the implementation of the big integer (and the toString() method) there is no way to know what's faster. number of iterations is also not enough, and you have no idea what that is anyway. You have no idea that this is indeed the implementation for the toString() for the specific implementation discussed. This discussion however is fertile, let's agree to disagree on this.

Comment: Thanks this is the most helpful answer for me although based on Svante's answer it seems the logarithm might be the best solution to this type of a problem...

Answer (score 1):

I timed three variants:

- repeated division
- logarithm
- string length

for lengths of multiples of 10.  I ran 10000 runs of each.

Results in microseconds:

```
length     division     logarithm     string length
---------------------------------------------------
  10           7           10            16
  20          14           14            26
  30          28           14            41
  40          46           14            59
  50          73           14            80
  60          91           14            80
  70         113           14            98
  80         136           14           106
  90         170           14           116
 100         197           14           129
```

There are artifacts of various origin in these data, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: When giving results, you really also should give the code producing these results. As it stands, you're pretty much asking us to trust you to know what you're doing (there's no way of validating what you said, without writing our own program from scratch, which may not produce the same results).

Comment: I shall post my code later this day.  However, if you write your own program from scratch, it will definitely not produce the same results, unless you use the same bignum implementation, the same string implementation, and the same logarithm implementation.  This is not a scientific article, just a quick test.  I used a reasonably recent SBCL on a reasonably recent Linux on a not so recent Acer notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It much depends on how numbers are given. I would interpret that you are given a number stored as a machine integer. In that case I think that best of all would be taking the logarithm of the number, which should give the answer in constant time.

Both your answers run in linear time, so they should be considered 
equivalent.

Comment: I don't know what makes you think taking log is not linear in the size of the input. It should be read, shouldn't it? As for "they should be equivalent". Constants do matter in questions like this. life aren't big O notation.

Comment: So, @amit, also division by 10 is not achieved in constant time?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, this is the fastest way to do this, assuming the input is an unsigned long or int of some kind:

```
int count_digits( unsigned long n ){
   unsigned long long quotient;
   unsigned int ctDigits = 1;
   while( n > 9 ){
      ctDigits++;
      quotient = (n >> 1) + (n >> 2);
      quotient += (quotient >> 4);   
      quotient += (quotient >> 8);   
      quotient += (quotient >> 16);   
      quotient = quotient >> 3;   
      n -= ((quotient << 2) + quotient) << 1; // computes the remainder
   }
   return ctDigits;
}
```

Any solution that uses division (which includes any itoa/string conversion) will be a lot slower because division is an expensive operation. In the world of high-speed computation division is a bad, bad thing.